# Tensorflow: concatenating 2 tensors of shapes containing None

Tags: python, tensorflow

My problem is the following: I have a tensor `A` of shape `[None, None, None, 3]` (`[batch_size, height, width, num_channels]`) and a tensor `B`. At runtime it is **guaranteed** that `A` and `B` will have the same shape. I would like to concatenate these two tensors along `num_channels` axis.

PS. Note that I simplified my original problem - so having a tensor of shape `[None, None, None, 6]` in the first place is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

Before asking a question I should probably try to run the code :) Using `tf.concat(values=[A, B], concat_dim=3)` seems to be working.